# Bash script to create montages of images with G'Mic

Tags: shell-script, image-manipulation

I need a bash script which will run through a folder of 100s of jpegs and create montages of every 30 images and output the montages with distinct file names.

The [G'Mic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmic/) command to create a montage from a folder of images*:

```
gmic *.jpg -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o output.jpg
```

*NOTE: Another zero may have to be added to the following part of the command to get it to work, e.g.:

`255,0,0,0,0,0 -o output.jpg`

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble? Are you just asking us to do your work for you and write the script from scratch? Please [edit] your question and show us what you have so far, we're not a free script writing service.

Comment: @terdon Obviously I don't know how to write a script for this, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. It's not laziness at all. It's a bounty question. I'm giving up 50 points of my reputation. I'm awarding the bounty to Rodin in 6 hours.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is not what the site is for, please don't do it. We're not a free script writing service, we're here to answer _specific_ questions. You need to read up a little on scripting, get a general idea of how to do this and at least *try*. It doesn't need to be a good attempt, just an attempt. Just something to show us you're not just too lazy to do your work and asking others to do it for you. Also, pro tip: it's often a question of phrasing, don't ask for a script, ask how you can achieve something, that often gets better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a researched question, but anyway, a small shell script can do something like:

```
c=0
for i in *.jpg; do
  c=$(($c+1))
  f="$f $i"
  test "$(expr $c % 30)" != 0 && continue
  gmic $f ... -o output-$c.jpg
  f=""
done
test -z "$f" || gmic $f ...  -o output-$(($c+1)).jpg
```